# Batch how to pass a parameter with space to function?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

how to pass a parameter with space or ; to function?

```
call :MyFunct "arg1" "arg2 arg2";"arg2"

:MyFunct

echo %~2
```

I would like to retrieve from %~1 "arg2 arg2";"arg2" but do not know how to do

Comment: But ```"one two";"tree"``` is two doublequoted arguments separated by a semicolon. `%~1` is the first argument, with any surrounding doublequotes removed. Have you tried `%*` for all of the arguments together?

Comment: thanks compo I updated the question, %* not good because I do not want the first argument

Comment: `%~1` is the first argument, (with enclosing doublequotes removed), `arg1`, `%~2` is the second argument, (with enclosing doublequotes removed), `arg2 arg2`, and `%~3` is the third argument, (with enclosing doublequotes removed), `arg2`. Spaces, commas and semicolons and even unquoted equals characters are considered as argument delimiters. How about you better show where the `call` argument string is coming from, and exactly what you wish to isolate from each part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample `"arg1" "arg2 arg2";"arg2"` the arguments are

```
arg1="arg1"
arg2="arg2 arg2"
arg3="arg2"
```

That's simply the rule of `cmd.exe`, any unquoted delimiter in the arguments splits arguments, delimiters are `<space>;,=`

If you want a different behavior, you need to write your own parsing function on the basis of `%*` or even better on the [bullet proof argument reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200316/463115)