# how to incorporate a batch file with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently using this method in calling batch files in vb.net:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("F:\ipconfigflushdns.bat")
    End Sub
```

Is it possible to incorporate the code written in the batch file so that I won't have to call it like the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you have shown will work. However, I would recommend that you rename your batch file with .cmd extension. This is more proper on Windows and causes there to be no ambiguity as to whether the 32-bit/64-bit Windows `cmd.exe` or the 16-bit MS-DOS compatibility `command.com` should be used loaded.

See: [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)

> Is it possible to incorporate the code
>   written in the batch file so that I
>   won't have to call it like the one
>   above?

Sure, it is possible. You'll need to take the typical approach for porting a program from one language to a very different one. That is, read the batch file and figure out manually how to do the same things using the .NET Framework.