# How to start batch file using nsis script?

Tags: nsis

I have successfully created exe file using NSIS.I have installed my application as windows service using following code:

```
Exec "$INSTDIR\bin\batch.bat"
```

I have checked this path

```
Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.
```

My service name successfully installed.
Final step of my installation process start the application using following code:

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN net start servicename
```

But this code did not working well.If i select the checkbox it does not start the services.

My scenario is:

Final step of my installation process is, I have one checkbox.If the user select checkbox then the service started immediately.else dont start the service.but both the cases the service must be installed.How to solve this?
How to start the service using nsis scrit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN net
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_PARAMETERS "start servicename"
```

or if you want to put the `net` command in a batch file or otherwise hide the console window, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12935584/3501) to one of your old questions...

Comment: Anders thanks.but this code is not working.service not yet started.also if i put net command in batch file.once the installation step also service started.I think that's not good idea.

Comment: Thanks..i have posted separated question related this question.