# How to run a batch file during Uninstallation using NSIS?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, nsis

I have created a Desktop Application which basically does some scan in the user's computer. I have created the setup using the NSIS. Everything works fine.

Even the Un-installation part works fine. However out of curiosity I wanted to add a feature during the Un-Installation part. I want that once the user uninstalls the application. The application and its files should be removed from the user's pc(that part I have completed). Next thing I want to do is that the user should be redirected to my website stating a message thanking him for using the Application.

For this I have created a batch file which have the website url as well as the User's name in the query string(which he gives during the registration). And I'm creating the batch file using C#.

How do run the batch file during the Uninstallation so that it can get me to the website.

The example url is as follows
www.application.com\username='abc'

I tried to get help from this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265141/executing-batch-file-in-nsis-installer) but couldnt solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

S. Vikneshwar

Comment: It would help if you show us the batch file code and how you execute it in NSIS...

Comment: The batch file contains nothing but the url which needs to run during the un installation process.
It contains

@echo off
start http://mywebsite.com/deactivation/user_verify.php?username='12345'

Comment: Apart from that there is nothing in the Batch file.

Comment: `start http://example.com` should work but so should ExecShell, using a batch file is just extra work...

Comment: @Anders I wrote ExecShell "cmd.exe" "$INSTDIR\test.bat" in the Uninstall part but somehow its not working.

Comment: I use that batch file as i need the User's name that i can only get after he/she installs it.

Comment: Do you mean %username%? For ExecShell, the first parameter should be ""

Comment: The whole thing can be sufficed as, I have to open a web page during the uninstallation of the application. I want to open a url based on the user name. And it has to be included during the Uninstallation part.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after spending few minutes myself I finally completed the process.

I created a batch file using C#.
The batch file consisted of the lines

@echo off
start http://application.com\username='abc' 
@echo off

Now I needed to run this batch file during the Uninstallation process.

So I tried using ExecShell, then Exec finaly ended up using ExecWait

The following is the code

```
Section "Uninstall"

ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\test.bat"'

;some code

SectionEnd
```

Hope this was useful.

Thanks

Comment: Using a batch file for this is silly, both start and ExecShell use ShellExecute internally. You can expand %username% in NSIS if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a batch file to open a URL, just use `ExecShell`...