# What's the difference between *.bat and *.cmd file?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, windows-shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)

Hi,

I am learning Windows Batch programming and come across this question:

What's the difference between **.bat** and **.cmd** file?

If they are the same, why need 2 of them?

BTW, what's the difference between **command.com** and **cmd.exe** ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Comment: @Blender If there is duplicate multiple questions, any actions in SO for join all questions in one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.bat` files are left-overs from DOS. `.cmd` files are for Window NT command processor or higher, and have more capabilities (some looping structures, the ability to call and return from procedural type blocks).

`command.com` was what ran the operating system and contained the internal commands like `dir` in DOS and early versions of Windows. It was replaced by `cmd.exe` when Windows NT was introduced, and was the first 32-bit command processor.

Answer (score 4):

This might help you
[Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/cmd-vs-bat-t1468592.html
A documented difference found in google groups 
The differences between .CMD and .BAT as far as CMD.EXE is concerned are: 
With extensions enabled, PATH/APPEND/PROMPT/SET/ASSOC in .CMD 
files will set ERRORLEVEL regardless of error. .BAT sets ERRORLEVEL 
only on errors.