# Why continue using extensions .bat instead of .cmd?

Tags: build, batch-file, continuous-integration, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)

I know that the `.cmd` is the successor of the `.bat` (`.cmd` files use 32-bit execution while the `.bat` files use 16-bit execution) but most repositories I see  on github that have a build script for windows continue using `.bat` extensions for build files.

As a general rule, anything you can do in a `.bat` file you can do in a `.cmd` file, but the reverse is usually not true.

There is a reason to use `.bat` instead of `.cmd` for build files?

**Edit:**

To clarify the difference between the extensions:
[Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)

Comment: How did you come to know that `.cmd` is the successor of `.bat`?

Comment: May be they are not aware of ".cmd". I heard it from you for the first time...;)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Comment: So is this not a duplicate of that same question you posted the link to?

Comment: @AcazSouza: this question is just a straight duplicate of that... but still, I wouldn't consider "successor" an appropriate term. They coexist just fine; people know of `.bat` and may be confused by `.cmd`, so even if you know of `.cmd` it may be best to avoid it for other people's sake. As you may imagine, this is self-perpetuating. But is that a problem? I think not.

Comment: No, i want to know if have a reason to why people use .bat files instead of .cmd files.

See build files in repositories in github, almost always use .bat files.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan (The CMD extension is limited to newer Windows systems and is not recognized in Windows 9x/Me systems. In Windows XP, Vista, and 7 there is little practical difference between the two extensions.) Font: http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm This is true?

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons come to mind:

1. cmd files have not been well publicised and I suspect a majority of people who use batch files do not know of their existance.  I did not and I use batch files on a regular basis, and have for close to 15 years.
2. Of those that do know, batch files have the benefit of being backwards compatible.  There is not a lot of direct benefits to using cmd files but allowing the same batch file to be run on practically any version of Windows and even DOS without any changes.