# Line length limit in xp batch file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

When running long command in .bat file (say 300 characters length)

for example:

```
Some_exe "C:/Documents and Settings/Some user/Some folder1/Some folder2/Some folder3/Some folder4 ... -Some_exe_arg1="arg 1 name" -Some_exe_arg2="arg 2 name" -Some_exe_arg3="arg 3 name"
```

Is there a limit on the line size CMD.exe can process?
Should i use .CMD or .BAT?
Is there any way i can overcome this limitation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *minimum* of the maximum batch line length is 8191 bytes!

This means that a line can be in any case 8191 bytes long, but it is also possible to create legal batch lines with nearly unlimited length.

Samples

```
echo Longline with 8191 characters.........

set "var=a"
echo UltraLongLine %var:4000chars=% %var:4000chars=% %var:4000chars=% %var:4000chars=%

echo Test <8000Chars <8000chars <8000chars .... <nul
```

The point is here, that all lines are less than 8192 bytes long after parsing

Comment: An even simpler valid long line is 20,000 spaces followed by `echo test`. Technically you are correct, the line length can exceed 8191 characters. But I don't see how this is helpful or in the spirit of the original question. I suppose there might be some scenario where the trick could be useful. But when I read the question, I assume it is the post parsing/functional line length that the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 6):

All versions of Windows from XP onward support a maximum batch line length of 8191 bytes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

Often times executables get around the command line length limit by allowing for parameter values to be specified in a file. For example, FINDSTR has a /G:filename option that specifies the name of a file that contains search strings.

There is no difference between .BAT vs .CMD with regard to line length. In fact, there is almost no difference between them at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/148991/1012053. *(Note - most of the comments questioning the accuracy of the linked answer predate the most recent edited version of the answer. The linked answer is now correct.)*