# MongoExport a collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection called User(with **userId** as primary key) and am trying to export certain documents based on the **Query** attribute supported by **MonogExport**. 
My MongoExport command looks like :

> mongoexport -h localhost -d mydb -o C:\account\user.json --collection user--query '{userId: {$in :[1233,1234,1235,1236]}}'

Based on the above, mongo creates a json file for us. But my major concern is, how to process this command, if length of this command increases to more than 8192 chracters(**Message Displayed** : the process command is too long)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem of mongo. Windows command line only takes 8191 characters per line.
[Refer here for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515988/how-to-avoid-batch-line-limit-8191-chars-per-line)