# Convert merge line batch script to shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I recently asked a question on the same forum and found a solution for it. Unfortunately, it has to be converted to UNIX. The issue was to merge lines from a csv file. Each line should end with a semi-colon (;) and if it doesn't combine the next line into it until find a semicolon again.

the solution that worked for me was

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "ln="
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "var=%%i"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if "!var:~-1!"==";" (echo !var!>>temp.csv) else (<nul set /p ="!var!">>temp.csv)
    endlocal
)
```

Would it be possible to convert to UNIX script?

Link to the original post is:   [Merge line with the next line if last character is a semicolon using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276782/merge-line-with-the-next-line-if-last-character-is-a-semicolon-using-batch-file/14282332)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Unix scripts." There are scripting languages, shells, pipeline utilities, and a multitude of programming languages. Do some research and write some code, then you'll be in a better position to ask good Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

next time if you want to do text processing, don't go to windows. :D

given that you have:

```
A;1;abc;<xml/>;
;2;def;<xml
>hello world</xml>;
;3;ghi;<xml/>;
```

your rule is:

> I need to combine lines such that if the line doesn't end end with a
>   semicolon (;), combine the next line into the current line.

```
awk '!/;$/{l=l""$0;next;}{print l""$0;l=""}' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "A;1;abc;<xml/>;
;2;def;<xml
>hello world</xml>;
;3;ghi;<xml/>;"|awk '!/;$/{l=l""$0;next;}{print l""$0;l=""}'
A;1;abc;<xml/>;
;2;def;<xml>hello world</xml>;
;3;ghi;<xml/>;
```

and it works in this case too:

```
kent$  cat ttt
A;1;abc;<xml/>;
;2;def;<xml
>h
e
l
l
o w
o
rld<
/xm
l>;
;3;ghi;<xml/>;

kent$  awk '!/;$/{l=l""$0;next;}{print l""$0;l=""}' ttt
A;1;abc;<xml/>;
;2;def;<xml>hello world</xml>;
;3;ghi;<xml/>;
```

Comment: Thanks @Kent. I am getting an error about the size of the data as each row of my CSV file is quite large. I found that I might need to use perl. is it be possible to use the same regex with perl?

Answer (score 0):

sed would be my option.

```
sed ':a;/[^;]$/{N;s/\n//;ta}' x.txt
```

sed reads in each line  and for each one
sets a tag (:a)
then checks to see if the line is missing the ; (/[^;]$/)
if it doesn't have the ; N reads in the next line and appends it to the current line with a new line seperating them.
s/\n// removes the newline
ta checks to see if the substitution was successfull and if so jumps to the :a tag to start the check again

Comment: Thanks @peteches. I am getting an error about the size of the data as each row of my CSV file is quite large. I found that I might need to use perl. is it be possible to use the same regex with perl?