# Remove Directory Command is not working as expected

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, batch-file

I have following batch script. It takes data from C:\Source into C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice.The source folder has two files 1. Web.config and 2. Web_PROD backup.

In the roll script there is a command to rename the config file. When I run the script first time, it is working fine. But when I run the script again , the renaming of file is not working. The root cause is that the remove directory command is not removing the folder. What need to be corrected here?

```
rem * STEP 1 taking backup of the folder

mkdir "C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\backup\b05232013v1\payrollservice"  
xcopy "C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice" "C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\backup\b05232013v1\payrollservice"  /E /y /H


rem * STEP 2  remove physical folder
rmdir "C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice"  


rem * STEP 3  create physical folder
mkdir "C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice"  


rem * STEP 4  Copy sourcecode to Production boxes
xcopy "C:\Source" "C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice" /E /y /H


rem * STEP 5  Rename teh config file
ren   C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice\Web.config WebLabbackup.config 
ren   C:\MyTEST\A\webroot\payrollservice\Web_PROD.config Web.config 

pause
```

From [**Xcopy**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

> /e : Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty.
>
> /y : Suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
>
> /h : Copies files with hidden and system file attributes. By default, xcopy does not copy hidden or system files.

**Reference**

1. [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**rmdir**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true)

> /s : Removes the specified directory and all subdirectories including any files. Use /s to remove a tree.
>   /q : Runs rmdir in quiet mode. Deletes directories without confirmation.

Figured it out. I need to use `/s /q` at the end of rmdir command.