# Python start Batch file without output in Python console

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file

.. with Arguments 
I want the Batch file to open its own Console and close it when its finished

```
os.startfile(path, param)
>> WindowsError: [Error 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation:
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the file from *.bat to *.cmd. I've had issues executing *.bat files before that were resolved by making it a *.cmd file. In your case, the problem has to do with what executable your system has associated with the *.bat extension. In particular, Python can't find *any* association (even though it should be cmd.exe).

The differences between the two file types are subtle and pretty well explored in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148968/2615940).

Comment: changed .bat to .cmd get same error
os.startfile(path) works but i need arguments