# Command works from prompt but not from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When I run the below command from the command prompt, it executes perfectly:-

```
C:\ouaf\CCB2402\bin>call splenviron -e CCB2402
Version ................ (OUAFVERSION) : 4.2.0.2.0
Database Type ............... (OUAFDB) : oracle
ORACLE_SID ............. (ORACLE_SID) : CCB_DB
```

etc...

But when I run the same thing from a batch file, it gives me an error.
Content of batch file:-

```
cd C:\ouaf\CCB2402\bin
call splenviron -e CCB2402
```

error given:-

```
Error detected while calling splstdinclude.cmd
```

contents of splenviron.cmd:-

```
@echo off
REM #
REM #% DocInfo: see the file docinfo.txt for instructions on how 
REM #% DocInfo: to use this file format for self documenting scripts.
REM #
REM #% PROGRAM: splenviron.cmd
REM #% PURPOSE: Initialise environment variables 
REM #%   USAGE:  splenviron.cmd -e <environment> [-c <command>] [-h] [-q] [-v]
REM #%   USAGE:     -e <environment>
REM #%   USAGE:           environment name in field $1 of /etc/cistab
REM #%   USAGE:           which also has an entry in ENVIRON.INI
REM #%   USAGE:     -c <command>
REM #%   USAGE:           command to run at end of script. Default is ksh
REM #%   USAGE:     -q
REM #%   USAGE:           dont show output from any commands in this script
REM #%   USAGE:           ( it will however show output from anything specified by -c 
REM #%   USAGE:     -v <verbose>
REM #%   USAGE:     -h   
REM #%   USAGE:           help
REM #%    DIST: release
REM #
if /I "%SPLDEBUG%" EQU "Y" @echo on

:START
    set SCRIPTNAME=%0
    for /f %%I in ('echo %0') do set SCRIPTDIR=%%~dpI

    if /I "%1" EQU "" goto USAGE
    set SPLCOMMAND=
    set SPLENVIRON=
    set VERBOSE=
    set SPLQUITE=


:GETARG
    if /I "%1" EQU "" goto NOMOREARGS
    if /I "%1" EQU "-h" goto USAGE
    if /I "%1" EQU "-e" if not defined SPLENVIRON set SPLENVIRON=%2
    if /I "%1" EQU "-c" if not defined SPLCOMMAND set SPLCOMMAND=%2
    if /I "%1" EQU "-v" if not defined VERBOSE set VERBOSE=Y
    if /I "%1" EQU "-q" if not defined SPLQUITE set SPLQUITE=Y
    shift
    goto GETARG


:NOMOREARGS
    if not defined SPLENVIRON goto USAGE
    if /I "%SPLENVIRON%" EQU "" goto USAGE


REM # **************************************************************
REM # **
REM # **   MAIN PART OF SCRIPT FILE
REM # **
REM # **************************************************************

:INIT
    REM ---------------------------------------------------
    REM Get SPLEBASE from CISTAB file
    REM ---------------------------------------------------
    set CISTABFILE=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\spl\etc\cistab
    if not exist %CISTABFILE% echo Unable to find CISTAB file %CISTABFILE%.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    findstr /i /c:"%SPLENVIRON%:" %CISTABFILE% >nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Environment %SPLENVIRON% is not in CISTAB file %CISTABFILE%.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"%SPLENVIRON%:" %CISTABFILE%') do set SPLEBASE=%%j:%%k
    if not defined SPLEBASE echo Unable to set SPLEBASE&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not exist %SPLEBASE% echo SPLEBASE directory %SPLEBASE% does not exist&&goto EXITWITHERROR

    REM ---------------------------------------------------
    REM Get SPLOUTPUT from CISTAB file
    REM ---------------------------------------------------
   for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"%SPLENVIRON%:" %CISTABFILE%') do set SPLOUTPUT=%%l:%%m
    if not defined SPLOUTPUT echo Unable to set SPLOUTPUT&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not exist %SPLOUTPUT% echo SPLOUTPUT directory %SPLOUTPUT% does not exist&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    set SPLAPP=%SPLOUTPUT%

    REM ---------------------------------------------------
    REM Set PERLLIB and ANT_HOME
    REM ---------------------------------------------------
    REM # Setup Perllib to include OUAF supplied PM modules.

    set ENVFILE=%SPLEBASE%\etc\ENVIRON.INI
   for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%i in ('type %ENVFILE% ^| findstr /i /c:"ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME="') do set ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME=%%j
    set PERL_HOME=%ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME%\perl
    set PERLLIB=%PERL_HOME%\lib;%PERL_HOME%\site\lib;%SPLEBASE%\bin\perllib
    set PERL5LIB=%PERL_HOME%\lib;%PERL_HOME%\site\lib;%SPLEBASE%\bin\perllib

   echo %PATH% | findstr /I "%PERL_HOME%\bin" > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%PERL_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

:SETANT
    set ANT_HOME=%SPLEBASE%\product\apache-ant
    echo %PATH% | findstr /I "%ANT_HOME%\bin" > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
   for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k ANT_OPT_MIN') do set ANT_OPT_MIN=%%I
   for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k ANT_OPT_MAX') do set ANT_OPT_MAX=%%I
   for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k ANT_ADDITIONAL_OPT') do set ANT_ADDITIONAL_OPT=%%I

   set CALC_ANT_OPT_MIN=
   set CALC_ANT_OPT_MAX=

   if "%ANT_OPT_MIN%" EQU "0" goto SKIP_ANT_OPT_MIN
   set CALC_ANT_OPT_MIN=-Xms%ANT_OPT_MIN%M

:SKIP_ANT_OPT_MIN
   if "%ANT_OPT_MAX%" EQU "0" goto SKIP_ANT_OPT_MAX
   set CALC_ANT_OPT_MAX=-Xmx%ANT_OPT_MAX%M

:SKIP_ANT_OPT_MAX
   set ANT_OPTS=%CALC_ANT_OPT_MIN% %CALC_ANT_OPT_MAX% %ANT_ADDITIONAL_OPT%


:SETUPSPLVARS
    REM ---------------------------------------------------
    REM Set environment variables
    REM ---------------------------------------------------


    echo %PATH% | findstr /I "%SPLEBASE%\bin" > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%SPLEBASE%\bin;%PATH%
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k FW_VERSION_NUM') do set FW_VERSION_NUM=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k SPLWAS') do set SPLWAS=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k CMPDB') do set CMPDB=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k SPLSYSTEMLOGS') do set SPLSYSTEMLOGS=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k SPLADMIN') do set SPLADMIN=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k SPLADMINGROUP') do set SPLADMINGROUP=%%I

    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k WEB_SERVER_HOME') do set WL_HOME=%%I

    set SPLBUILD=%SPLEBASE%\cobol\build
    set SPLSOURCE=%SPLEBASE%\cobol\source
    set SPLRUN=%SPLEBASE%\runtime
    set SPLSYSTEMLOGS=%SPLEBASE%\logs\system

    echo %PATH% | findstr /I "%SPLRUN%" > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%SPLRUN%;%PATH%
    REM
    REM Setup which compiler is to be used. Only supported option is microfocus
    set SPLCOMP=microfocus
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k WEB_ISEXPANDED') do set WEB_ISEXPANDED=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k SPLApp') do set SPLApp=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k appViewer') do set appViewer=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k XAIApp') do set XAIApp=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k help') do set help=%%I

    REM Setup display bill ini file - DOC1
    set ONLINEBILLINI=%SPLEBASE%\etc\billdirfile.ini
    set ONLINEDOCINI=%SPLEBASE%\etc\doc1dirfile.ini

:SETUPWEBAPPSERVER

    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k JAVA_HOME') do set JAVA_HOME=%%I
    if not exist %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe echo ERROR - %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe file does not exists. Exiting.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    echo %PATH% | findstr /I "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
    if /I "%SPLWAS%" EQU "WLS" goto AFTERSETUPWEBAPPSERVER
    echo ERROR - Only Weblogic is supported on Windows for OUAF. Exiting.&&goto EXITWITHERROR

:AFTERSETUPWEBAPPSERVER

:SETUPDB
    goto SETUP%CMPDB%
    echo ERROR - Cannot find DB setup routine. Exiting.&&goto EXITWITHERROR

:SETUPMSSQL

    goto AFTERSETUPDB

:SETUPORACLE

        REM We will gather the basic Database Home  
        for /f "delims=`" %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME') do set ORACLE_HOME=%%~sI

    if not defined ORACLE_HOME echo ERROR - environment variable ORACLE_HOME should be set prior to OUAF operation. Exiting.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not exist %ORACLE_HOME% echo ERROR - ORACLE_HOME %ORACLE_HOME% directory does not exist. Exiting.&&goto EXITWITHERROR


    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k ORACLE_SID') do set ORACLE_SID=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k NLS_LANG') do set NLS_LANG=%%I
    for /f %%I in ('call perl -e"$a=uc \"%NLS_LANG%\";print $a;"') do set NLS_LANG=%%I

        set NLS_DATE_FORMAT=YYYY-MM-DD
        set NLS_SORT=BINARY
    goto AFTERSETUPDB

:AFTERSETUPDB

:SETUPCOBOL

        for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k RJVM') do set RJVM=%%I
    if /I "%RJVM%" EQU "false"  goto AFTERSETUPCOBOL
    for /f %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k COBMODE') do set COBMODE=%%I 

    REM Set needed variables for COBOL Installations: 
    for /f "delims=`" %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k CHILD_JVM_JAVA_HOME') do set CHILD_JVM_JAVA_HOME=%%~sI
        for /f "delims=`" %%I in ('call perl %SPLEBASE%\bin\getconfvalue.plx -k COBDIR') do set COBDIR=%%~sI
    set SPLCOBCPY=%SPLSOURCE%\cm;%SPLEBASE%\services;%SPLSOURCE%


:SETUPMICROFOCUSNETEXPRESS

    if not exist "%COBDIR%"\bin\cblrtss.dll goto SETUPMICROFOCUSAPPSERVER
    echo %PATH% | findstr /I %COBDIR%\bin > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%COBDIR%\bin;%SPLRUN%;%PATH%
    goto AFTERSETUPCOBOL

:SETUPMICROFOCUSAPPSERVER

    if not exist %COBDIR%\cblrtss.dll echo Unable to find %COBDIR%\bin\cblrtss.dll nor %COBDIR%\cblrtss.dll. Please check your COBOL installation. Exiting.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    echo %PATH% | findstr /I %COBDIR% > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 set PATH=%COBDIR%;%SPLRUN%;%PATH%
        goto AFTERSETUPCOBOL

:AFTERSETUPCOBOL

:CHECKENNVARS
    REM # Check environment setup and readability of directories.
    call %SPLEBASE%\bin\splstdinclude.cmd SPLcheckenvvars
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error detected while calling splstdinclude.cmd.&&goto EXITWITHERROR

    if /I "%SPLQUITE%" EQU "Y" goto AFTERQUITE
    echo Version ................ (OUAFVERSION) : %FW_VERSION_NUM%
    echo Database Type ............... (OUAFDB) : %CMPDB%
    if /I "%CMPDB%" EQU "oracle" echo ORACLE_SID ............. (ORACLE_SID) : %ORACLE_SID%
    if /I "%CMPDB%" EQU "oracle" echo NLS_LANG ................. (NLS_LANG) : %NLS_LANG%
    echo Environment Name ....... (SPLENVIRON) : %SPLENVIRON%
    echo Environment Code Directory (SPLEBASE) : %SPLEBASE%
    echo App Output Dir - Logs ... (SPLOUTPUT) : %SPLOUTPUT%
    echo Build Directory .......... (SPLBUILD) : %SPLBUILD%
    echo Runtime Directory .......... (SPLRUN) : %SPLRUN%
    echo Cobol Copy Path ......... (SPLCOBCPY) : %SPLCOBCPY%

:AFTERQUITE

    if /I "%VERBOSE%" NEQ "Y" goto AFTERVERBOSE
    echo Running on Operating SYSTEM (OS) : %OS%
    echo Running on command interpreter (COMSPEC) : %COMSPEC%
    echo Java Version
    java -version
    echo Perl Version
    perl -V

:AFTERVERBOSE

    cd /d %SPLEBASE%
    if not defined CMENV goto AFTERCMENV
    if exist %CMENV% call %CMENV%

:AFTERCMENV

    if exist %SPLEBASE%\scripts\cm\cmenv.cmd call %SPLEBASE%\scripts\cm\cmenv.cmd
    if /I "%SPLCOMMAND%" NEQ "" call %SPLCOMMAND%

goto ENDOFBAT


:USAGE
    echo USAGE:
    echo USAGE: %SCRIPTNAME% is the install program for Oracle application installations
    echo USAGE:
    echo USAGE: %SCRIPTNAME% -e environment [-c command] [-h]
    echo USAGE:                -e environment
    echo USAGE:                      environment name in first field of cistab file
    echo USAGE:                      which also has an entry in ENVIRON.INI
    echo USAGE:                -c command
    echo USAGE:                      command to run at end of script
    echo USAGE:                -h   
    echo USAGE:                      help
    echo USAGE:
    goto EXITWITHERROR

:EXITWITHERROR
    exit /B 1
    goto ENDOFBAT

:ENDOFBAT
```

Contents of splstdinclude.cmd

```
REM #
REM #% DocInfo: LEAVE THE BELOW TWO LINES IN THE RESULTANTSHELL SCRIPT
REM #% DocInfo: see the file docinfo.txt for instructions on how 
REM #% DocInfo: to use this file format for self documenting scripts.
REM #
REM #%     PROGRAM: splstdinclude.cmd
REM #%     PURPOSE: Common functions used in most SPL scripts
REM #% DESCRIPTION: Common functions used in most SPL scripts 
REM #%       USAGE: call splstdinclude.cmd arg where arg1 is the function name
REM #%       USAGE:   additional args can be passed to the function using
REM #%       USAGE:   arg1, arg2, ... , arg5
REM #%        DIST: release
REM #%  MODHISTORY: 000101:DC:Created
REM #%  MODHISTORY: 00
REM #
REM #
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM #

:START
if /I "%1" EQU "" echo Function name not provided.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
set FUNCTIONNAME=%1
for /f "delims=~" %%I in ('echo %2') do set PARM1=%%~I
for /f "delims=~" %%I in ('echo %3') do set PARM2=%%~I
for /f "delims=~" %%I in ('echo %4') do set PARM3=%%~I
for /f "delims=~" %%I in ('echo %5') do set PARM4=%%~I
for /f "delims=~" %%I in ('echo %6') do set PARM5=%%~I
goto %FUNCTIONNAME%

REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM # start of this function
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:SPLCHECKENVVARS

    REM # The Following Variables are required to be set before  splenviron.sh is even started.
    if not defined SPLOUTPUT echo Environment variable SPLOUTPUT is not defined.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not exist %SPLOUTPUT% echo Unable to find directory %SPLOUTPUT%.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not defined JAVA_HOME echo Environment variable JAVA_HOME is not defined.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not defined SPLENVIRON echo Environment variable SPLENVIRON is not defined.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not defined SPLEBASE echo Environment variable SPLEBASE is not defined.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not exist %SPLEBASE%\bin echo Unable to find directory %SPLEBASE%\bin.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    for /f %%I in ('call perl -e"$a=lc "%CMPDB%";print $a;"') do set CMPDB=%%I
    if not defined SPLCOMPLOG goto AFTERSPLCHECKENVVARS
:AFTERSPLCHECKENVVARS
    goto ENDOFBAT
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM # end of this function
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM # start of this function
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:LOG

    REM # The Following Variables are required to be set before  splenviron.sh is even started.
    if not defined SPLCOMPLOG echo Environment variable SPLCOMPLOG is not defined.&&goto EXITWITHERROR
    if not defined PARM1 set PARM1= 
    if /I "%PARM2%" EQU "-q" call perl -e"use SPL::splLog;my $log=SPL::splLog->new($ENV{'SPLCOMPLOG'});$log->info('-q', '%PARM1%');"
    if /I "%PARM2%" NEQ "-q" call perl -e"use SPL::splLog;my $log=SPL::splLog->new($ENV{'SPLCOMPLOG'});$log->info('%PARM1%');"

:AFTERLOG
    goto ENDOFBAT
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM # end of this function
REM #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

:EXITWITHERROR
    exit /B 1

:ENDOFBAT
```

It seems that the program exits after setting the errorlevel to 1. Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Try `C:` followed by `cd \ouaf\CCB2402\bin` followed by `call splenviron -e CCB2402`

Comment: or use ´cd` with the `/d` switch: `cd /d C:\ouaf\CCB2402\bin` Or use `pushd` instead of `cd`

Comment: Guys I don't think the error is coming because of the cd command. I tried your suggestions but got the same error. The error might be because of the execution of the above scripts which I have pasted now. I looked at it from different angles but am not able to see where i am going wrong. Kindly help.. Thanks

Comment: As you aren't explicitly setting exit /B 0 in ENDOFBAT, whatever the last errorlevel was set will be returned to the calling `.cmd`. Are there any other error messages? Perhaps the cal perl is failing, but being masked by the for statement.

Comment: @ScottC I reset the errorlevel to 0 and ran the batch but still it gave me the same error. So it probably means that the value of errorlevel is being changed inside the cmd files. I then added "exit /B 0" in endofbat and the batch executed successfully without errors. But this is not the solution I am looking for as I don't want to change the contents of the cmd  files. Much appreciate your inputs on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the extension of your batch!

From [Difference .bat vs .cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011048/463115)

> .cmd enables built-in commands to change Errorlevel to 0 on success.

When you call your .cmd directly this works, so the errorlevel will be reset to 0 after the `set CMPDB=%%I` command.

But when you call it from a .bat file it doesn't reset anymore, even when the code is still included from a .cmd file, it's executed with the .bat logic.

So the solution should be to rename your .bat also to .cmd

Answer (score 0):

OK, potential reason: `splstdinclude.cmd` may not be altering the errorlevel at all. The last thing done in `splenviron.cmd` before calling `splstdinclude.cmd` is to adjust the path if the findstr has set an errorlevel.

I'm guessing that the command prompt you run from has COBDIR in the path, but a double click on the bat file doesn't.

You can check this by adding an `echo %errorlevel%` either side of your `call %SPLEBASE%\bin\splstdinclude.cmd SPLcheckenvvars` command.