# How to convert batch file (.bat) to .cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file (.bat) and I want to convert it to .cmd file:

```
rem^ &@echo off
rem^ &call :'sub
rem^ &exit /b
:'sub
rem^ &echo begin batch
rem^ &cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%~f0"
rem^ &echo end batch
rem^ &exit /b
```

Comment: not right "rename file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertBatToCmd.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo ConvertBatToCmd.bat
if not exist "%1" echo call with file to be converted as parameter & goto :eof
ren "%1" "%~n1.cmd"
```

Usage: `convertBatToCmd myfile.bat`

(sorry, couldn't resist...)

back to seriousity: [more infos here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148968/2152082)

Comment: plus one, just because I think on the same idea **`:)`**

Comment: Another one here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the file from myfile.bat to myfile.cmd