# Windows Path variable is ignored in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to use maven in a batch file but it says that "mvm" is an invalid command. I have tried to do it manually and it seems that the command only works once.

Path (Shown with new lines):

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Users\█\Maven\bin;
C:\Users\█\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Test Code:

```
mvm --version
```

Error:

```
'mvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Does it work if you call C:\Users\___\Maven\bin\mvm.exe instead?

Comment: @SomethingDark I have just figured out that now it doesnt work in CMD anymore.

Comment: If it doesn't work even with the full path, that's a problem with Maven.

Comment: It turns out they were .cmd files not .bat files.

Comment: Shouldn't matter at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd?rq=1

Comment: Maven command is mvn, not mvm.. If this typo solves your problem, you could delete this question.