# findstr command not working in windows batch file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, findstr

I made a simple batch file in windows.
it works reporting to find the URL including error.
but all URL echo only success.

wget command stdout seems like empty. redirection pipe is not work. what's wrong??

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (TEST.txt) do call :request %%i
set /p in=Finish!

:request
echo | set /p= %1 >> result.txt
wget.exe -T 3 --tries=2 %1 | findstr /I "error"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo error >> result.txt
) else (
    echo success >> result.txt
)
```

My problem is solved.
Modified code from a good answer

```
@echo off
set logFile="log.txt"
set resultFile="result.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in (TEST.txt) do call :request %%i 
set /p in=Finish!

:request
echo|set /p= %1 >> %resultFile%
wget.exe -P download -T 3 --tries=2 %1  2>&1 | tee -a %logFile% | findstr /I "error" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo error >> result.txt
) else (
    echo success >> result.txt
)
```

Comment: what is the extenstion of you batch file? `.bat` or `.cmd` ?

Comment: It's .bat. Is it related?

Comment: oh!! thanks! I didn't think about difference .bat between .cmd file. reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Comment: yes, so errorlevel will be reset with cmd :) Is it working now?

Comment: is it working now as `.cmd` ?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - FINDSTR is an external command, so it always sets ERRORLEVEL to 0 or 1. The `.bat` vs `.cmd` issue only arises with some internal commands.

Comment: @dbenham. I am aware of that, but tested this issue with `.cmd` and did not replicate OP issue, hence the comment. Not sure if it helped him though so was waiting on a response.

Comment: My gnu wget writes the diagnostic info to stderr, so redirection would be needed. See my answer.

Comment: This works well after i change it to ".cmd". I use wget downloaded in the gnu utility, but in the case of findstr, I could use it without any extra work. I don't understand that findstr is an external command.

Comment: oh.. Is your statement related to the tee command in my modified code?

Answer (score 1):

The wget diagnostic information that you are trying to read is written to stderr, not stdout. So you simply need to redirect stderr to stdout before your pipe.

Assuming all your wget arguments are correct, I would write the code as follows:

```
@echo off
>result.txt (for /f "delims=" %%i in (TEST.txt) do (
  wget.exe -T 3 --tries=2 %%I 2>&1|findstr /i error >nul&&echo %%i ERROR||echo %%i SUCCESS
))
echo Finished!
```

Comment: EDIT - Fixed the code logic - my original answer had it reversed, and the critical redirection was missing

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to `echo` only to `result.txt` instead to terminal/console.

```
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo error >> result.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
) else (
    echo success >> result.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
)
```

These changes not allowed to display on console/terminal