# Running 'serverless' command on terminal showing question in Chinese

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, serverless, serverless-framework

I have this problem if I install serverless framework using `npm install -g serverless` I encounter this message in Chinese on my computer (windows 11).

once I ran `serverless` on the terminal I get this message

```
C:\Users\User>serverless
 当前未检测到 Serverless 项目，是否希望新建一个项目？ Yes
 请选择你希望创建的 Serverless 应用 (Use arrow keys or type to search)
> generate-usersig-for-tencent-im - Generate usersig for Tencent Cloud IM.
  abc-starter
  fullstack
  laravel-starter - Laravel 项目模版
  flask-starter - Flask 项目模版
  eggjs-starter - Egg.js 项目模版
  koa-starter - Koa.js 项目模版
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)
```

Expected output is this:

```
What do you want to make? (Use arrow keys)
  AWS - Node.js - starter
  AWS - Node.js - HTTP API
  AWS - Node.js - Scheduled Task
  AWS - Node.js - SQS Worker
  AWS - Node.js - Express API
  AWS - Node.js - Express API with DynamoDB
  AWS - Python - Starter
  AWS - Python - HTTP API
  AWS - Python - Scheduled Task
  AWS - Python - SQS Worker
  AWS - Python - Flask API
  AWS - Python - Flask API with DynamoDB
  Other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already fixed it. Just by changing my Date&TimeZone from Hongkong to Singapore UTC+8 and It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're located in China? [`serverless`' "Getting Started" guide](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/getting-started) makes explicit mention of this as a feature:

> Note: users based in China get a setup centered around the chinese Tencent provider. To use AWS instead, set the following environment variable: `SERVERLESS_PLATFORM_VENDOR=aws`.

As it mentions, simply [set the environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018145/export-set-environment-variables-in-windows-through-a-shell-script) as per their instructions to bypass this.

Comment: Already fixed it by changing my time zone. Thanks for answering.