# .bat and .cmd different on ERRORLEVEL, who determines SET's behavior?

Tags: batch-file

As I just find out, `SET`'s behavior is different for `.bat` and for `.cmd`. My experiment shows that, `SET`'s behavior is determined by the startup batch file's extension(.bat or .cmd), NOT by the file extension that `SET` statement resides in.

This is such a vague corner of Windows NT CMD batch script engine, [Ben Hoffstein talks about it a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148991/151453). And I'd like to know, whether my conclusion is correct? Or, does Microsoft docs formally talks about this somewhere？

I'd also like to know, is there way to check, or even change, current *mode*？bat mode or cmd mode? If neither, I have to accept the fact that we batch script authors(especially when writing batch as functions) can make no assumptions.

### My experiment below

Run from Windows 7 SP1.

#### showerr.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :SetErrorlevel 40
set var=1
echo Err=%ERRORLEVEL%

exit /b 0

REM ==== Functions below ====

:SetErrorlevel
exit /b %1
```

### showerr.cmd

same as showerr.bat .

### start-subcmd.bat

```
call showerr.cmd
```

### start-subbat.cmd

```
call showerr.bat
```

Result is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This didn't surprised me, although I never tested this particular point before...

*The following information comes from my personal experiences. As far as I know, this is not documented at any place*

A "subroutine" called via `call subFile.bat` is what I called *internal subroutine*. It *inherits* several status from its parent, like the "echo on/off" and others. Now, I know that it also inherits the "BAT|CMD" mode.

Of course, the most known values that an internal subroutine shares with its parent are the environment variables.

A subroutine called via `cmd /C subFile.bat` is an *external subroutine*. When it starts, it have a fresh set of initial values of several status, including the "BAT|CMD" mode.

See this test:

**start-SubBat.cmd**

```
call ShowErr.bat
cmd /C ShowErr.bat
```

Output:

```
Err=0
Err=40
```

**start-SubCmd.bat**

```
call ShowErr.cmd
cmd /C ShowErr.cmd
```

Output:

```
Err=40
Err=0
```

The way to know what is the "current mode" is very simple: first set the errorlevel to 1 via `verify other 2>NUL` (that is the MS suggested method to do that) and then execute `set var=1`. If the new %errorlevel% is 1, you are in BAT mode; if it is 0, you are in CMD mode.

Just to complete this topic, a "subroutine" executed via its name with no `call` nor `cmd /C` commands (i.e. just `subFile.bat`) is called *overlay*: it *replaces* the calling program in every aspect.

The commands that change the way they modifies the %errorlevel% when they are placed in a BAT or CMD file are briefly described under **Table 3** at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that running `.bat`, the `set` is leaving `errorlevel` unchanged, but this has been "corrected" for `.cmd` to setting `errorlevel` to 0 as the `set` succeeded.